# Unable to add an element to a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with my Build function code in a game I am creating. Here is the problem:

When I build (and have the gold to afford it (an in-game variable to tell how much money you have so you can afford an item ) the game does not create the element in the 2D integer array: 'game'.

I believe this is a problem of scope but I cannot solve it.

```
 static void Build(int type) {
    System.out.println("Select location\n");
    System.out.println("Column:");
    int col = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Row:");
    int row = in.nextInt();
    if (row > 9) {
        System.out.println("Bad choice");
        Build(type);
    } else if (row < 1) {
        System.out.println("Bad choice");
        Build(type);
    } else if (col > 9) {
        System.out.println("Bad choice");
        Build(type);
    } else if (col < 1) {
        System.out.println("Bad choice");
        Build(type);
    } else if (game[row][col] != 0) {
        System.out.println("Something is already there, or there is water blocking your way.");
        Build(type);
    } else {
        if (type == 1) {
            if (food > 1) {
                if (wood > 1) {
                    game[row][col] = type;
                    food -= 1;
                    wood -= 1;
                    numOfHomes++; //must start at 1 to keep a base
                    game[col][row] = type;
                    System.out.println("Built a gold mine at: "+col+" by "+row);
                    Start();

                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("You cannot afford a gold mine.");
                Start();
            }
        }
        if (type == 2) {
            if (money > 1) {
                if (wood > 1) {
                    game[row][col] = type;
                    money -= 1;
                    wood -= 1;
                    numOfWoodCutters += 1; //must start at 1 to keep a base
                    game[col][row] = type;
                    System.out.println("Built a woodcutter at: "+col+" by "+row);
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("You cannot afford a Woodcutter.");
            Start();


        }
        money = money * numOfHomes;
        troops = troops * numOfCamps;
        wood = wood * numOfWoodCutters;
    }
}
```

My code is this, if you need to know:

`static int[][] game = new int[10][10];`
Which is not in the psvm (public static void main) scope.

**But this seems to be the main problem: `game[col][row] = type;`
Whenever that is declared it does nothing, but it should do something.**

Comment: where's & what's the error ?

Comment: If you give exact error (compiler or runtime) it will be easier to help..

Comment: Have you used a debugger? On what line does that occur? Having gold means nothing to us trying to help if your game logic is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lays in your initial if-else chain .

For example

```
if (row > 9) {
    System.out.println("Bad choice");
    Build(type);
} else if (row < 1) {
    System.out.println("Bad choice");
    Build(type);
} else if (col > 9) {
```

You don't need an else when you check `col` because it has nothing to do with the value of `row`.

Also, not sure if this is intentional, but you are mirroring your board across the diagonal by doing

```
game[row][col] = type;
... 
game[col][row] = type;
```

And this is hard to determine on my phone, but it looks like this else block lines up with your `if (type == 2)`

```
else {
        System.err.println("You cannot afford a Woodcutter.");
```